# C# Windows service default GroupOrderList

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I'm developing a C# service which communicates with a GUI starting with the user desktop session.
As far as i used to know, services are guaranteed to start before the user session, but sometimes ( randomly ) the gui starts before the service itself ( the gui is put in common startup entries ).

I was reading about the GroupOrderList, so basically i have three questions.

- Since my service doesn't specify any group, is this a normal
  behaviour ?
- Which is the default group/order for services without an
  explicit group declaration ?
- Which group should i put my service in
  to be sure it starts before desktop session ( and still continues
  working ) ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the solution to make sure the service is started before starting the GUI, or can you perhaps let the GUI 'poll' until the service is up?

Comment: the gui is started by windows autostart mechanism, so i have no control over it ... the poll solution is already implemented, but i'm searching for something cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the native Win32 API [ChangeServiceConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can set the new service Group ( sixth parameter ).